# Cloud Formation-opsworks-Code pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-opsworks, aws-codepipeline

If I use Cloud Formation-opsworks-Code pipeline, how do I deploy to three different environments using a single Code Pipeline:

Stack → Layer → Dev Environment → Test Env → Prod Env.

All three environments to have different instances on them.

Is this possible? or Do I need to have different Layers for different environments inside a single stack?
Please suggest any best practices.